# Method invocation oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a function to compare two images. The function compiles and there are no warnings.

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compare_images(id1 integer, id2 integer) return integer AS
image1 ORDimage;
image2 ORDimage;
image_sig1 ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature;
 image_sig2 ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature;
 wartosc INTEGER;
 BEGIN
 SELECT picture INTO image1 FROM pictures_tab
  WHERE id_picture = id1;
SELECT picture INTO image2 FROM pictures_tab
  WHERE id_picture = id2;
  image_sig1.generateSignature(image1);
  image_sig2.generateSignature(image2);
  wartosc := ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature.isSimilar(image_sig1,
 image_sig2,'color=1.0,texture=0,shape=0,location=0',10);
 return wartosc;
  END;
```

When I try to run the function in a following way:

```
select compare_images(33,34) from dual;
```

I am sure that arguments are correct.

I receive an error:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: przy "SAGA.COMPARE_IMAGES", line 12
30625. 00000 -  "method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed"
*Cause:    A member method of a type is being invoked with a NULL SELF
           argument.
*Action:   Change the method invocation to pass in a valid self argument.
```

Comment: You know ORDImageSignature is deprecated, in 11g, right? What data type is the column in the table? Your code seems to be assuming it is stored as a signature, but the name and your description suggests it's an actual image - either an ORDImage or a BLOB?

Comment: In the table I have ORDImages. It was written that I can create ORDImageSignature from ORDImage using function generateSignature(ORDImage), so I find the ORDImages with given ids, create signatures from them and compare with isSimilar().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDImageSignature is deprecated in 11g and doesn't appear much in the documentation. From the [10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14297/ch_imgref.htm#BABIJFFE):

> The ORDImageSignature object must either be initialized and inserted into a table or be created using a temporary LOB, to successfully generate a signature for the object.

The signature variable needs to be initialised from the static `init()` method before you can call the `generateSignature()` method on that instance.

So your function would need to do:

```
  image_sig1 := ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature.init();
  image_sig1.generateSignature(image1);
  image_sig2 := ORDSYS.ORDImageSignature.init();
  image_sig2.generateSignature(image2);
```